# Correct procedure to take limit

Tags: limits

What is $$\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}\\{\epsilon\rightarrow1}}\frac{a^2-(a-1-\epsilon)^2}{a^2-(a-1+\epsilon)^2}?$$

Does limit value approach $1$?

$$\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}\\{\epsilon\rightarrow1}}\frac{a^2-(a-1-\epsilon)^2}{a^2-(a-1+\epsilon)^2}=\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}{\epsilon\rightarrow1}}\frac{{a^2-(a-1)^2(1-\frac{\epsilon}{a-1})^2}}{{a^2-(a-1)^2(1-\frac{\epsilon}{a-1})^2}}=\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}}\frac{{a^2-(a-1)^2}}{{a^2-(a-1)^2}}=1 $$

Or

$$\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}\\{\epsilon\rightarrow1}}\frac{a^2-(a-1-\epsilon)^2}{a^2-(a-1+\epsilon)^2}=\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}}\frac{a^2-(a-2)^2}{a^2-a^2}=\frac{a^2-(a-2)^2}{0}=\infty$$

Or

$$\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}\\{\epsilon\rightarrow1}}\frac{a^2-(a-1-\epsilon)^2}{a^2-(a-1+\epsilon)^2}=\lim_{\substack{a\rightarrow\infty}\\{\epsilon\rightarrow1}}\frac{a^2(1-\frac{(a-1-\epsilon)^2}{a^2})}{a^2(1-\frac{(a-1+\epsilon)^2}{a^2})}=\frac{1-1}{1-1}=\frac{0}{0}$$

If you fix $\epsilon$(say $0.9999999999$) you get $1$(as $a\rightarrow\infty$)?

Comment: Doesn't that prove that the double limit is not well-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio is $$R(a,\varepsilon)=\frac{a^2-(a-1-\epsilon)^2}{a^2-(a-1+\epsilon)^2}=\frac{1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}\cdot\frac{2a-1-\varepsilon}{2a-1+\varepsilon}=\frac{1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}\cdot\left(1-\frac{2\varepsilon}{2a-1+\varepsilon}\right).$$
Note that $$\lim_{a\to\infty,\varepsilon\to1,\varepsilon\lt1}\frac{1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}=+\infty,\qquad\lim_{a\to\infty,\varepsilon\to1,\varepsilon\gt1}\frac{1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}=-\infty,$$
while
$$\lim_{a\to\infty,\varepsilon\to1}\frac{2\varepsilon}{2a-1+\varepsilon}=0,$$
hence
$$\lim_{a\to\infty,\varepsilon\to1}\left(1-\frac{2\varepsilon}{2a-1+\varepsilon}\right)=1.$$
Finally,
$$\lim_{a\to\infty,\varepsilon\to1,\varepsilon\lt1}R(a,\varepsilon)=+\infty\cdot1=+\infty,$$
and
$$\lim_{a\to\infty,\varepsilon\to1,\varepsilon\gt1}R(a,\varepsilon)=-\infty\cdot1=-\infty.$$
Likewise,
$$\lim_{a\to\infty,\color{red}{\varepsilon\to0}}R(a,\varepsilon)=1\cdot1=1.$$
**Edit:** For every $\varepsilon\ne1$,
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}R(a,\varepsilon)=\frac{1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon},$$
and, for every $a\gt1$,
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to1,\varepsilon\gt1}R(a,\varepsilon)=-\infty,\qquad\lim_{\varepsilon\to1,\varepsilon\lt1}R(a,\varepsilon)=+\infty.$$

Comment: Fix epsilon where? Get this as limit of what? Please be specific.

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: No, this forgets terms in the expansion of $(a-1)^2(1-c/(a-1))^2=(a-1)^2-2c(a-1)+O(1)$.

Comment: And, if I may, reading *carefully* my answer might help you to get out of the conundrum you seem to be lost in...

Comment: ?? What is the relevance of $a=1$ and $a\lt1$ to study limits when $a\to\infty$? No idea of where you are heading to.

Comment: ?? *Reading* the first displayed equation in my answer yields $$R(\epsilon,\epsilon)=\frac{1+\epsilon}{1-3\epsilon},$$ and you *might* be able to compute the limit of this when $\epsilon\to1$.

Comment: ((At least 5 comments by the OP are now deleted.))

Comment: 2+ years on the site and 140+ questions asked, but you still do not know how the site works?

Comment: Indeed *answerers* did their job on the present page.

Comment: ((At least 3 other comments by the OP are now deleted.))

Answer (score 1):

Take $\epsilon = 1+1/a$ and note that $\epsilon \to 1$ when $a \to \infty$, then we have the following limit.
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a^2-(a-1-1-1/a)^2}{a^2-(a-1+1+1/a)^2} = \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a^2-(a-2-1/a)^2}{a^2-(a+1/a)^2} = -\infty$$

Now take $\epsilon = 1-1/a$ and note that $\epsilon \to 1$ when $a \to \infty$, then we have the following limit.
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a^2-(a-1-1+1/a)^2}{a^2-(a-1+1-1/a)^2} = \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a^2-(a-2+1/a)^2}{a^2-(a-1/a)^2} = \infty$$

In conclusion, you can obtain two different values if you take two different paths when calculating this limit, therefore the limit doesn't exists.

Comment: If you fix, then it's a limit in ONE variable, not two.

Comment: You are calculating another limit, not the original one. If you have two variables in your limit, both have to vary, you can't fix one of them and then do the limit. In some cases this is possible, but not in general.

Comment: No, the result is $1999999$, but even if the result was $1$, it doesn't help your case.

Comment: You made wrong manipulations. $(a-1-0.999999)^2 = (a-1.999999)^2$ and $(a-1+0.999999)^2 = (a-0.000001)^2$. There is no way the numerator and the denominator will be equal.

Comment: To make this clear. 
$$(a-1-0.999999)^2 = (a-1)^2\frac{(a-1-0.999999)^2}{(a-1)^2} = (a-1)^2(1-\frac{0.999999}{a-1})^2$$

and

$$(a-1+0.999999)^2 = (a-1)^2\frac{(a-1+0.999999)^2}{(a-1)^2} = (a-1)^2(1+\frac{0.999999}{a-1})^2$$

Comment: Now you can argue that when $a\to\infty$, $1\pm\frac{0.999999}{a-1}\to 1$, so the sign doesn't matter. But the thing is that when you do the limit for $a$, it has to be for the entire expression at once, you can't just choose the terms you want to make $a\to\infty$ first. And in this case you did, you choose to make the limit for $1\pm\frac{0.999999}{a-1}$ before the others terms, this is wrong.

Comment: Don't take me wrong, but I think you should make more exercises and study more by yourself before going back to this questions. You are missing basic stuff about limits.

Comment: If you fix $a=1$, and $\epsilon\neq \pm1$ the expression will be $1$.